# email validation with regex expression --- not working properly JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, email-validation

I have a handleSubmit function that fires when a form is submitted. I am collecting a user email as input. My existing code does not reject invalid entries and I'm not exactly sure what I am missing...

Ideally, an invalid response will trigger the alert box but as of now all input is being pushed to the database.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    let participantsName = e.target.participantsName.value;
    let participantsEmail = e.target.participantsEmail.value;
    let pattern = /^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/;


    e.preventDefault();

    if (participantsName) {
        e.target.participantsName.value = "";
        Participants.insert({
            name: participantsName
        });
    }
    if (participantsEmail.match(pattern)) {
        e.target.participantsEmail.value = "";
        Participants.insert({
            email: participantsEmail
        });
        alert("Please enter a valid email address")
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem then?

Comment: Why is this `alert("Please enter a valid email address")` inside the `if` that checks if the email matches the pattern? It should be outside, in an `else` clause.

Comment: Can you give an example of an invalid input that has been submitted that your program didn't catch?

Comment: @Catalyst: Thank you for catching that I will update accordingly.

Comment: Your regex is wrong on so many levels... For example there are several valid TLD that are more than 3 characters long. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78353/how-far-should-one-take-e-mail-address-validation

Comment: If you want to properly check an email address, you should first convert the domain to ASCII from punycode, and then check that each label is valid, and that the total length of all labels is less than the max allowed length. Or test for a @ and then send an email to verify that the email was delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to a more extensive one

```
let pattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Comment: It is still not enough. You must first convert the domain part of the input to punycode.

Answer (score 0):

A preliminary validation regex from html5

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

Expanded

```
 # http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#valid-e-mail-address

 ^ 
 [a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+ 
 @
 [a-zA-Z0-9] 
 (?:
      [a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61} 
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
 )?
 (?:
      \. 
      [a-zA-Z0-9] 
      (?:
           [a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61} 
           [a-zA-Z0-9] 
      )?
 )*
 $
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the responses. With some small changes I got the code to work!

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
let participantsName = e.target.participantsName.value;
let participantsEmail = e.target.participantsEmail.value;
let pattern = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;



e.preventDefault();

if(participantsName && participantsEmail.match(pattern)){
  e.target.participantsName.value = "";
  e.target.participantsEmail.value = "";
    Participants.insert({
        name: participantsName,
        email: participantsEmail
    });
} else {
  e.target.participantsName.value = "";
  e.target.participantsEmail.value = "";
  alert("Please enter a valid email address")
 }
}
```